# Automatically take PDF files from SolidWorks PDM and merge into one portfolio

Tags: pdf, solidworks

I am trying to automate a process of creating a PDF portfolio with multiple PDF reports that are stored in SolidWorks PDM. (not merging these PDFs into one PDF, but to create a portfolio where these files are still separated). The thing I am not very sure about is that if I should create this function as a Java script and execute it in a PDF editor environment; or it makes more sense to create a macro in the PDM environment that calls a function in a PDF editor application. I am very new to automating working process as such, is there a third platform where it is easier to call different applications and would provide a more customized UI for others to use?